# JQuery Multiple List Accordion Issue

Tags: jquery, list, menu, accordion

I have two lists that I would like to function similar to an accordian, when the specified element is clicked, the specified list is hidden, and on click again it would toggle to shown.

The HTML:

```
    <ul class="acc" id="acc">
            <li>
                    <h3 class="slide">CATEGORIES</h3>
                    <div class="acc-section">
                    <div class="acc-content view">

                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                    <h3 class="slide2">CATEGORIES</h3>
                    <div class="acc-section">
                    <div class="acc-content view2">

                    <ul>

                   <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>

</ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

I have accomplished this for both lists using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('h3.slide').toggle(function() { 
    $('div.view').fadeOut('slow');
    return false; 
     }, 
        function() { 
            $('div.view').fadeIn('slow'); 
            return false; 
    }); 
    $('h3.slide2').toggle(function() { 
    $('div.view2').fadeOut('slow');
    return false; 
     }, 
        function() { 
            $('div.view2').fadeIn('slow'); 
            return false; 
    }); 
});
```

My issue with this is that it is not 'dynamic' and if I were to add another list in the future then I would also have to the above code. I would prefer to be able to just use the one small piece of code and reuse the same two class names for the click able element and the show/hide element. I have attempt to accomplish this with the following code but am unable to get it to work properly:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('h3.slide').toggle(function() { 
    $(this).siblings('div.view').fadeOut('slow');
    return false; 
     }, 
        function() { 
            $(this).siblings('div.view').fadeIn('slow'); 
            return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the effort but I was able to solve this using .slideToggle: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 0):

To make is event apply to elements that need to load after the DOM initially loaded, try jQuery on() function. Something like:

```
$(function(){
  $('h3.slide').on('toggle', function() { 
    $('div.view').fadeOut('slow');
    return false; 
    }, 
      function() { 
      $('div.view').fadeIn('slow'); 
      return false; 
  }); 
  $('h3.slide2').on('toggle', function() { 
    $('div.view2').fadeOut('slow');
    return false; 
    }, 
      function() { 
      $('div.view2').fadeIn('slow'); 
      return false;
  }); 
});
```

Hope that helps.

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Whilst that doesn't directly relate to my issue, learning about .on was helpful, and will be helpful in in the future thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery "closest" instead of siblings here. http://api.jquery.com/closest/

For example:

```
$(this).closest('div.view').fadeOut('slow');
```

If this doesn't suit your needs, please post your CSS, and I can help you better.

Comment: I wasn't able to use that as (from what I could tell) closest moves up the dom tree form the starting point, I needed to move down it, but I was able to solve the problem. Thanks for the advice.